# Read variable values from file in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am new to windows shell scripting

I have a text file with contents in the following format

```
input.txt

find1=replace1
find2=replace2
find3=replace3
```

I also have a set of windows commands like

```
findAndReplace.exe -r "*.java" find1 replace1
findAndReplace.exe -r "*.java" find2 replace2
findAndReplace.exe -r "*.java" find3 replace3
```

I want to make this as a script which reads each find-replace pair from input.txt and performs the above steps

Comment: Read the help of the `for` command (type `for /?` in command prompt); you will find an `/F` option that is designed for parsing text files, so try to read your `input.txt` file with such loop and return to here in case you encounter problems...

Comment: You need this command http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, the FOR command should be of use here. It will split the line into two variables, %%a and %%b for you. Remove the `echo` when it produces the commands you want.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a IN (`TYPE "input.txt"`) DO (
    echo  findAndReplace.exe -r "*.java" %%a %%b
)
```